# Could not save the List Changes to Server in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I am working in Sharepoint Designer 2013 for my Sharepoint in Windows 365. I want to create a custom Form using Sharepoint Designer however when I click create a new form and then save this new form I get an error message:

[image]

I tried cleaning out the cache in location c:/Users/user/Appdata/Local/Microsoft/WebsiteCache

Has anyone had this problem and found a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you follow some advice mentioned below:

- **Step 1**: Create a new list item on your list. If it works, go to step 2. If doesn't, check our list columns (or content types of that list) - **specially calculated fields and lookup fields**.
- **Step 2**: Create new custom form by SharePoint Designer 2013. If it doesn't work, try to clear SPD cache in location:

> c:/Users/[your current user]/Appdata/Local/Microsoft/WebsiteCache

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has landed here in 2020 onwards looking for the answer, the reason is that Microsoft have deprecated this feature.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-designer-could-not-save-list-changes-to-server/m-p/1352320