# SharePoint Designer Site Configuration error while creating forms

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have configure SharePoint site in my local system, While I am going to create forms I am getting error[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Designer deprecated please check these two articles:

https://microsoft365.today/microsoft-365/powerapps/sharepoint-designer-feature-deprecation/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/what-s-deprecated-or-removed-from-sharepoint-...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to follow some advice mentioned below:

Step 1: Create a new list item on your list. If it works, go to step 2. If doesn't, check our list columns (or content types of that list) - specially calculated fields and lookup fields.
Step 2: Create new custom form by SharePoint Designer 2013. If it doesn't work, try to clear SPD cache in location:
c:/Users/[your current user]/Appdata/Local/Microsoft/WebsiteCache

Reference:
[Could not save the List Changes to Server in Sharepoint 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146757/could-not-save-the-list-changes-to-server-in-sharepoint-2013)

Here are another similar thread you could have a look:
["could not save the list changes to the server" in designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205243/could-not-save-the-list-changes-to-the-server-in-designer)